# TransformException duplicate entry for AnnotatedHandlerFinder.class

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this error when trying to build.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':directory:transformClassesWithJarMergingForWnyDebug'.
    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/squareup/otto/AnnotatedHandlerFinder.class
```

and now getting this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':directory:packageAllWnyDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
    > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/squareup/otto/AnnotatedHandlerFinder.class
```

This started when I upgrade top level file dependencies i.e.

```
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
}
```

Comment: Try to `defaultConfig { ...  multiDexEnabled true
 ... } ` in your gradle and rebuild your project.

Comment: @pRaNaY I have already used multiDexEnabled true in default config.

Comment: Have you tried to `exclude module` in your build.gradle's **configurations.all** block?  You can specify the AnnotatedHandler there.